# No API request not called when closed tab restored

Tags: caching, browser, remix

I'd like to call API request when I close browser tab and restore it by ctrl + shift + t key.

What I use is Chrome browser and it works as expected when I set "Disable cache" at developer tool.

I'm using Remix and no request is called when I look at server side logs.

Set "Cache-Control": "no-cache" but not worked